# Run a web app coded in PHP locally

Tags: php, database, web, server

I need help with making a webpage from several files and I am not sure how to go about it. I'm not sure how to follow these instructions can someone help me out.

Install:

1. Copy contents of folder "upload_to_server" to your server.
2. Open "includes/config.php" and edit $cfg['db_server'], $cfg['db_username'], $cfg['db_password'], $cfg['db_database'] to be your database details, and $cfg['site_url'] to be the URL to the site with a trailing slash e.g. "http://www.example.com/" or "http://www .example.com/example/" (if it has been uploaded to a sub folder named "example".
3. Import database.sql into your database

![Here is a picture of the files for the site][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eHOb.pn g

Comment: You just need to find a tutorial on how to set up a web server. Do some Googling, there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: I did, I tried using mysql and stuff but im just not sure how to make these files into a webpage(check the image)

Comment: "Image is no longer available."

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7eHOb.png

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as (the problem) has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a local web stack first. WAMP or XAMPP for Windows, LAMP for Linux, or MAMP for Mac

You are then going to have to locate your web folder, which is usually called `www`, `htdocs`, or `public_html`. This is where your files need to go.

You can import databases from PhpMyAdmin, which should come bundled with your web stack.

Then you use `http://localhost/whatever-folder-you-added` to access it.